# Vector minimizing the norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X_0$ be a finite-dimensional linear subspace of the linear normed space $X$. Show, that for every vector $x \in X$ there exists at least one vector $x_0 \in X_0$ such that:
$$\|x-x_0\|=\inf\{\|x-y\|:y \in X_0\}$$

So basically I need to prove that there exists at least one "optimal" element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. Consider the closed ball $B[x,\Vert x\Vert]=\left\{y\in X:\Vert x-y\Vert\leq\Vert x\Vert\right\}$. Notice that $0$ is an element of $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$. Since $X_0$ is finite-dimensional, then $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$ is compact, so there is a $x_0\in X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$ which minimizes distance to $x$ among elements of $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$. This $x_0$ will also minimiza distance to $x$ in $X_0$.

Comment: Can it be proved another way?

Comment: @luka5z All ways I can think now involve compactness/sequential compactness, and I do believe this is somewhat necessary.

Comment: Can you explain why we know that $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$ is compact?

Comment: @luka5z If $X_0$ is a finite dimensional space, then all the norms are equivalent ([here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math561_spring2011/norm_equiv.pdf)). This allows us to apply [Heine-Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) to $X_0$: $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$ is a closed, bounded subset of $X_0$.

Comment: thanks. and why $X_0$ is closed?

Comment: @luka5z $X_0$ is indeed closed, but you see that my argument does not use that: $X_0\cap B[x,\Vert x\Vert]$ is a closed, bounded **subset of $X_0$**. We're just using the topology of $X_0$, and not of $X$.

Comment: oh, I see know. B is closed in $X$, and so is in $X_0$ with induced topology

Comment: and the last statement is because norm is continuous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14949/discussion-between-luiz-cordeiro-and-luka5z).